# Why does Strong's have two different entries for the word "Adam"?

Tags: hebrew, tools-of-biblical-studies, etymology

As far as I can tell, these are the exact same word, down to the cantillation marks.  And H121 even says, "the same as H120".

From Strong's:

> H120 - 'adam **אָדָם**, from אָדַם (H119):
>
> *man, mankind*
>
> 1. man, human being
> 2. man, mankind (much more frequently intended sense in OT)
> 3. Adam, first man
> 4. city in Jordan valley

and

> H121 - 'adam **אָדָם**, the same as אָדָם (H120):
>
> *Adam = "red"*
>
> 1. first man
> 2. city in Jordan valley

**Why the two separate entries?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strong’s is distinguishing between the [proper noun](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H121&t=KJV) and the [common noun](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H120&t=KJV).* See also, for instance, other pairs:

- [H127](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/127.htm) אֲדָמָה (ground)
- [H128](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/128.htm) אֲדָמָה (Adamah, a city in Naphtali)

or

- [H168](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/168.htm) אֹ֫הֶל (tent)
- [H169](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/169.htm) אֹ֫הֶל (Ohel, a name mentioned in 1 Chronicles)

And we’re only on *aleph*...

By the way, those aren’t really [cantillation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation) but [nekudot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud), representing vowels.

And since we’re on the topic, please remember that [Strong’s is a concordance, not a lexicon](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/923/3555).

---

<sub>*For more on how this pair can occasionally be confusing, see another question on this site: [Hosea 6.7: “like men”, “like Adam”, or “at Adam”?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13040/3555)</sub>

Comment: But the glosses it gives seem to indicate both are used as proper nouns!